# Lebesgue integral w.r.t law and Stieltjes integral w.r.t distribution function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider a generic probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and a measurable space 
$(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is meant to denote the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. A measurable function 
 $$X\,:\,\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
such that $\sigma(X)\subseteq\mathcal{F}$ is then referred to as random variable and allows for the definition of a law (or distribution)
$$\mu:\mathcal{B}\rightarrow[0,1]\quad\text{such that}\quad B\mapsto\mathbb{P}(X\in B)\quad\text{for all}\quad B\in\mathcal{B}.$$
Since all intervals of the type $(-\infty,x]$ are elements of $\mathcal{B}$, it follows that one can define a distribution function
$$F(x)=\mu(-\infty,x].$$
Due to the properties of $\mu$, $F$ is easily shown to be monotonically increasing, right-continuous, and normalized to take values in $[0,1]$.

Building on these results most texts in probability theory (at least those that I have encountered so far) simply go on asserting that - provided certain conditions on $f$ are met - we can define the Stieltjes integral w.r.t. distribution function $F$
$$\int_a^bf(x)\,\text{d}F(x)$$  to be equal to Lebesgue integral w.r.t. the law of $X$
$$\int_{(a,b]}f\,\text{d}\mu,$$
such that $\int_a^bf(x)\,\text{d}F(x)$ and $\int_{(a,b]}\,f\,\text{d}\mu$ are essentially just two different ways of writing exactly the same thing.

As $F$ and $\mu$ are related by the fact that $F(x)=\mu(-\infty,x]$, I am not really comfortable to accept the above as a matter of definition. Therefore, I was wondering whether there is any way to see that the statement above is actually true?

Thank you very much.

Best wishes,
Jon

Comment: Essentially $F(x_2)-F(x_1)=\mu (x_2-x_1)$.  Then define $dF(x)$ and $d\mu$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I am afraid, though, that I do not follow. Since $\mu:\mathcal{B}\rightarrow[0,1]$, I don't see how $(x_1-x_2)$ could be an argument of $\mu$. As the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure is defined such that $F(x_2)-F(x_1)=\mu(x_1,x_2]$, is it legitimate to argue that $\text{d}F=F(x+\text{d}x)-F(x)=\mu(x,x+\text{d}x]=\text{d}\mu$? I have to admit, that I have a hard time believing that $\mu(x,x+\text{d}x]=\text{d}\mu$, i.e. that the differential of $\mu$ is the measure assigned to the interval $(x,x+\text{d}x]$.

Comment: Your comment is correct.  I should have written $\mu(x_1,x_2)$.  As for $d\mu$, I don't see any other way to define it other than $d\mu=\mu(x,x+dx)$.